# ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint even when both fields are of the same type

Tags: mysql, database, key, constraints, workbench

When trying to build a mysql database consisting of two tables, some reason I am getting Error 1215 and I'm unable to find the cause. Both fields are of the same type. I am trying to do this with MySQL workbench. Anyone knows the cause of this error?

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Classified_tweets`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Classified_tweets` (
  `QueryID` INT NULL,
  `TweetID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `TweetKeyword` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TweetUsername` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TweetDate` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TweetLocation` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TweetContent` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `TweetLabel` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TweetID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Words_frequency`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Words_frequency` (
  `QueryID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Word` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Label` INT NULL,
  `Frequency` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`QueryID`, `Word`),
  INDEX `fk_Words_frequency_Classified_tweets_idx` (`QueryID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Words_frequency_Classified_tweets`
    FOREIGN KEY (`QueryID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Classified_tweets` (`QueryID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the primary key on `Classified_tweets` as `TweetID`.

You should be using this column for the foreign key relationship.  Perhaps:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Words_frequency` (
  `TweetID` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `Word` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Label` INT NULL,
  `Frequency` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`QueryID`, `Word`),
  INDEX `fk_Words_frequency_Classified_tweets_idx` (`QueryID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Words_frequency_Classified_tweets`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TweetID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Classified_tweets` (`TweetID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Note:  I changed the first column from `QueryId` to `TweetId`.  This should fix the problem, although your intention might be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can only refer to a column which is a primary key or a unique attribute. If you want to refer to query ID itself, then make it as the primary key or a unique attribute. or change the Words_frequency table to refer to tweetID.